# Link text is missing in HTML?

Tags: html

I just test Html code with the help validator tool. It seems Link text is missing in HTML below code. How to fix this error.

```
<ul class="social">
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="poshytip  facebook" title="Become a fan"></a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="poshytip  twitter" title="Follow my tweets"></a></li> -->
                <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="poshytip  youtube" title="Working on..."></a></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS-

```
.rounded .facebook{ background: url(../img/social-icons/rounded/facebook_32.png); }
```

I am using CSS too. Its Look Like Below. 
[image]

I dont want to insert text in this.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the text

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="poshytip facebook" title="Become a fan">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Combine this with .facebook { text-indent: -9999em; } to hide the text.

Comment: make the font-size: 0 to hide the text